# Is it possible to combine linear VAR restrictions with SVAR A/B restrictions?

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, structural-equation-modeling, restrictions

I have been exploring the various restrictions that are commonly applied to (S)VAR models in textbooks on multivariate time series, noting that linear restrictions on VAR models seem to be treated separately from A/B-type restrictions on SVAR models. I was wondering if it is possible to combine restrictions on VAR models, such as zero restrictions on lag matrices, with restrictions on the A/B matrices of SVAR models? If so, how would each system have to be estimated? (I assume OLS equation-by-equation won't be a good idea?)

Pointers towards (accessible) theoretical materials, reference papers and applicable software would be appreciated.